# Unable to get all events when sending messages using PushSharp

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

I send push notifications using PushSharp.
I am facing a problem while receiving the responses in the delegate methods as mentioned in Redth documentation on GitHub.

So, of the say 10 GCM Registration Ids that I send a particular message, I receive 9 responses only. I require this kind of response to make sure that in case of canonical Ids returned I should be able to update my database accordingly.

Is this behavior by design (i.e to not wait for all the responses from GCM) which results in few responses getting dropped ?

Below is my code snippets for better understanding

//Create our push services broker

```
    //Create our push services broker
    var broker = new PushBroker();
    broker.OnNotificationSent += new NotificationSentDelegate(NotificationSent);
    broker.OnNotificationFailed += new    PushSharp.Core.NotificationFailedDelegate(NotificationFailed);

    broker.OnChannelException += new ChannelExceptionDelegate(ChannelException);
    broker.OnServiceException += new ServiceExceptionDelegate(ServiceException);

    broker.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += new DeviceSubscriptionChangedDelegate(DeviceSubscriptionChanged);
    broker.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += new PushSharp.Core.DeviceSubscriptionExpiredDelegate(DeviceSubscriptionExpired);

    broker.OnChannelCreated += new ChannelCreatedDelegate(ChannelCreated);
    broker.OnChannelDestroyed += new ChannelDestroyedDelegate(ChannelDestroyed);

    //---------------------------
    // ANDROID GCM NOTIFICATIONS
    //---------------------------
    broker.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(senderID, senderAuthToken, applicationIdPackageName));

    GcmNotification gcm = new GcmNotification();
    gcm.RegistrationIds.Add(deviceRegistrationId1);
    gcm.RegistrationIds.Add(deviceRegistrationId2);
    //and so on

    gcm.WithJson("{\"Test\":\"" + notificationMsg + "\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}");

    //Stop and wait for the queues to drains
    broker.StopAllServices(true);
```

//<

Please advise if I am missing something in this implementation.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're not registering to see the failed notifications as you associate the delegate with the PushSharp delegate and not your own:

```
 broker.OnNotificationFailed += new    PushSharp.Core.NotificationFailedDelegate(NotificationFailed);
```

should match your:

```
 broker.OnNotificationSent += new NotificationSentDelegate(NotificationSent);
```